# PHP: Get the LINUX PID of a command

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm running a command in my linux server (Ubuntu).
For example:

```
screen -A -h 1500 -m -dmS test_command_one /home/SKY-users/SKY-001/./script
```

Is there any way to the PID of this background progress which screen name is: `test_command_one`?

ps aux | grep test_command_one:

```
root      6573  8.1  2.4 271688 123804 pts/4   Ss+  Oct19   3:04 /home/SKY-users/SKY-001/./ ...
```

I'd like to get back this PID: `6573`

PHP: (easy)

```
<?php 
$output = shell_exec('sudo ps aux | grep test_command_one');
$array = explode("\n", $output);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: how do you run this? in a php script? how is this related to php?

Comment: I've started this command by a PHP script, and I'd like to get back the PID of this command!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit:

By combining with code by @WagnerVaz

```
$mystring = "test_command_one";
exec("ps aux | grep 'screen .* $mystring' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -1", $out);
print "The PID is: " . $out[0];
```

### Explanation

- ps aux - shows processes for all users and hidden processes too
- grep - filters only lines containing "screen" and then "test_command_one" in the same line
- grep -v - removes from output the very same line which we are executing, because it will also be matched
- awk '{ print $2 }' - awk splits input into columns and uses multiple spaces as separator. This print contents of 2nd column
- head -1 - limits output only to the first line. This is in case you have multiple screen running, only first ID is returned.

Comment: Inside PHPs exec(). See second argument http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php which will return you output of the command. Don't forget to trim it.

Comment: btw, PHP says: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/process.php on line 2`

Comment: @romaninsh can you please take a look at my issue  which is similar to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331958/how-to-execute-script-in-silent-mode-to-get-rid-from-browser-hang-on

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $mystring = "test_command_one";
    exec("ps aux | grep \"${mystring}\" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -1", $out);
    print "The PID is: " . $out[0];
?>
```

Edited: Combined with shell exec of @romaninsh

Comment: this wouldn't work since "cut" will not treat repeating spaces as a single separator. Also it's important to exclude "grep" command.

Comment: Yea, forgot to exclude the grep :P

Comment: used part of your code in my answer. Thanks and here's up-vote.

Comment: Hm, thanks so much! However I don't understand how it's working :P Could you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
echo exec('pidof test_command_one');
```

It's shorter ;)

See also: [pidof manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof)

Answer (score -1):

```
$pid = shell_exec($cmd . " && echo $!");
```

Comment: Why && instead of &, Carpetsmoker?

Answer (score -2):

Or, just use:

```
$pid = getmypid();
```

Comment: this will return the PHP pid of the current process. The question was to get the PID of the process you started via exec or another process.